# IE11 promise strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, promise, bluebird, aurelia

We have noticed really strange behaviour in IE11 when starting Aurelia application.
It occurs only if it is first time you start app in new window/tab AND mouse cursor is NOT in IE window area (for example program is run from command line with given url - which is important scenario for us). Application then stays on index.html with static content but and nothing happens.
Until you move cursor over window... Then magically app continues without any errors and any issues.

As far as I could debug, issue occurs when script enters System.import('core-js') promise. It happens with or without using bluebird promise.

This is body from "index.html".

```
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('core-js').then(function () {
    return System.import('webcomponents.js/MutationObserver');
  }).then(function () {
    return System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
  });
</script>
```

EDIT:

I noticed that what helps is to put promise with timeout (at least 1000ms). Do you have any idea if any better solution exists?

```
<script src="jspm_packages/npm/bluebird@3.3.3/js/browser/bluebird.js"></script>
<script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
<script>
    // IE11 hack for mutation observer/promises error
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
        window.setTimeout(
            function () {
                resolve();
            }, 1000);
    });

    System.import('core-js').then(function() {
        return System.import('webcomponents.js/MutationObserver');
    }).then(function() {
        return System.import('aurelia-bootstrapper');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sounds like a nasty little bug. You may be able to force initialisation by triggering a mouseover event (eg on page load), but then take care that it is not triggered twice (safety is probably already in place but you need to make sure).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround for the bug which is caused by IE11 mutation observer behavior w.r.t scheduling. This workaround works with bluebird but not other polyfills:

```
 // use timers for scheduling
 Promise.setScheduler(function(fn) { setTimeout(fn); });
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, however in this scenario it won't work :( It seems like system.js is changing Promise object, because after importing system.js script Promise.setScheduler function becomes undefined and I need to use promises after importing this package. Do you have any idea how can I workaround this?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you please provide some example?

Comment: ```System.import("bluebird").then(function(Promise) {
    // your code here
});```

Comment: I did as you wrote, and it is even stranger, IE hangs, it is even impossible to debug it, whole tab needs to be killed and application is not starting in any way. Seems like I found workaround (see EDIT section in my question) but that cannot be used in production code.